# How do you dry homemade pasta so that it stays straight?

Tags: pasta, drying

I did a big batch of homemade pasta (linguini) with stand mixer + pasta cutter attachment. But they all warped during the 24h drying process. I then need a huge bag to store them as they take up a lot of space.

Is there a trick to make them dry straight?

Comment: How did you dry them? Flat? On what sort of surface? Please give us some base stats so we know what didn't work for you.

Comment: I hung them on a clothes drying rack !

Answer (score 2):

Hang-dry pasta on a pole will result in the most straight pastas.

the finer (smaller) diameter pole you can find will result in smaller curvature in the pasta where they bend on the pole.

I've seen people use a metallic cloth dryer or metallic coat hangers (hanging on a pole of some sort)

Comment: Generally, I agree... but at this point, that could be what the OP already did and is unsatisfied with the results.

Comment: If you're really anal retentive, you might be able to fit stuff hung on a smaller diameter inside that hung on a larger diameter, if you *really* wanted to get it into as small an area as possible ... but it's probably more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @Max I did hang it on a metallic rack. The problem is not the curvature induced by the rack pole in itself, but the pastas actually warp afterwards when they dry, making storage very problematic.  I have 1,5 kg of pastas but they fill a whole grocery bag because they are not straight like pastas you can buy in boxes.

Answer (score 1):

If you freeze home made pasta, you get a much better fresh-pasta taste and texture than by drying it- plus it doesn't go wavy.

Coat the pasta liberally with flour then shake off the excess, put it in a plastic bag and pop it in the freezer. When you want to use it, let it defrost in the fridge for a few hours. This works for gyoza wrappers as well.

Comment: While this may be true, it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for you advice. I'll try it out, I just don't have enough space in my freezer !

Answer (score 1):

Drying on a pole/hanging is an invitation for curving, unless your indoor humidity is quite high. The outer surface dries faster than the core, creating stress. The stress caused by uneven moisture makes the curves. You want to briefly surface dry so the pasta does not stick together, which can be done on a rack. After some minutes, put the pasta on a tray(s) you can cover with a box to slow dehydration. Allow the outer surfaces to equalize with the cores by very slow drying. Lift the box every few hours to allow wet air to escape. Cover the pasta again. Repeat. The goal is to dry as slowly as possible but avoid mold.